# Python 2.7: list concatenation for class objects within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is for an assignment (albeit turned utterly on its head so that I still have to think through any solutions provided and actually learn something here...) and I've spent the last three hours doing various tutorials around the web and thumbing through the Python manual, Daniweb, and here, and just cannot figure out how to synthesize these concepts.

I have a bunch of input coming from a text file (let's say it's the below) from which the first item on each line is going to turn into the key for a dictionary, and the latter three items go into a class 'Fruit' that ends up describing the things, as you'd imagine.

```
lemon?yellow?sour?not
lemon?yellow?sour?yes
orange?orange?sweet?yes
grape?purple?sweet?yes
```

I'd like the key "lemon" created from this file to return the descriptors "yellow sour not" AND "yellow sour yes" as a list.

```
class Fruit(object):
'''Describes fruits'''
    def __init__(self,color,flavor,tasty):
        self.color = color
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.tasty = tasty

    def getColor(self): return self.color
    def getFlavor(self): return self.flavor
    def getTasty(self): return self.tasty
    def description(self): return self.color,self.flavor,self.tasty

fruity = {}

for line in inputFile:   
    n,c,f,t = line.split('?')
    indFruit = fruit(c,f,t)
    fruity[n] = [fruit.description]
```

All this has worked so far, except of course that the second time the file hits the key "lemon" it overwrites the "yellow sour not" with "yellow sour yes" (in other words as written it seems to be doing everything it's supposed to do.)

So I'm working on a way to handle that lemon problem. I tried:

```
fruity = {}
fruitlist = []

for line in inputFile:   
    n,c,f,t = line.split('?')
    indFruit = fruit(c,f,t)
    fruity[n] = fruitlist.append(indFruit)
```

which produces

```
{(lemon): none, (orange): none, (grape): none}
```

and then

```
fruity = {}
fruitlist = []

for line in inputFile:   
    n,c,f,t = line.split('?')
    indFruit = fruit(c,f,t)
    fruitlist.append(indFruit)
    fruity[n] = fruitlist
```

which is a bit of an overachiever as it produces:

```
{(lemon): [(yellow, sour, not),(yellow,sour,yes),(orange,sweet,yes),(grape,sweet,yes)}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it do what I want, which is to display:

```
{(lemon): [(yellow, sour, not),(yellow,sour,yes)], (orange): [(orange, sweet, yes)]}
and so on.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dictionary mapping keywords such as "lemon" to a list, map it to a `set` and have `("yellow", "sour", "not")` or `("yellow", "sour", "yes")` as a `tuple` instead of your **Fruit** class and add them to the set object.

The set will ensure that you only retain unique items. If later you find that you need to have them as a list for some reason, then simply call `list(my_dict["lemon"])`

If you are insistent on using your custom class, then look into making your **Fruit** class hashable by defining `__hash__` method in your class. You could do this in your class by simply aggregating the values ("yellow" etc.) into a tuple and returning the hash of that tuple when `__hash__` is called. Just a quick and dirty method. You might want to research for better ways to create hashes for whatever values you might be storing if they are not necessarily strings such as "Yellow" etc. and could be more complex data types.

Note that the values added to a set cannot be a list because lists are not hashable. That is why I suggested a tuple (or defining a `__hash__` method for your class).

Also, you might find the **setdefault()** and **get()** method in a dictionary object useful. I recommend looking them up in the python documentation or google for them.

Comment: Thank you! What you say about mapping the items to a set makes sense, but alas, the assignment specs do mandate that I leave it as a class. I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say to make the class hashable, but that gives me reading material and a place to move forward on this. I appreciate your help- I'll read up and try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's your last line:

```
fruity[n] = fruitlist
```

This is setting the value of fruity[n] to the entire list.  I'm guessing you'd want to do something like using a default dict, so you can get an individual list for each fruit (you could also use `setdefault`, but why not be more readable?)

```
from collections import defaultdict
fruity = defaultdict(lambda : []) # new list for each item

#... at the end of your forloop
fruity[n].append(indFruit)
```

Check out the docs on [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for more. It's also dead simple to create your own defaultdict or switch your last line to:

```
 fruity.setdefault(n, [])
 fruity[n].append(indFruit)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion- looking at the docs, this may well be the best solution (or at least it looks that way at midnight.) I appreciate your input and will try this out as well!

Comment: @user2113818 but do you actually understand the problem with your code? The issue is that each time you are assigning the same list to each item. To see this, try doing `all(v is fruitlist for k,v in fruity.items())`. *Every* element is fruitlist.

Comment: Yes, thank you; my output indicated that that was going on. It was getting around that without reverting to a "solution" that gave me no values that was the problem (or at least the problem of the moment. I'm learning a lot doing this one, but, as is usual with me, I don't learn it particularly quickly.)